# Pass net.socket as argument

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

How can I pass the net.socket class as argument?
My code:

```
this.server = net.createServer(this.onAccept.bind(this));
  this.server.listen(this.port);
}

Server.prototype.onAccept = function () {
  // PASS SOCKET AS ARGUMENT HERE 
  var client = new Client(ONLYMYSOCKETCLASS);
```

Answer (score 1):

1. It doesn't really make sense to put `onAccept()` on the prototype if you're just going to call `.bind()` which returns a (bound) *copy* of that function. The primary purpose of putting things on a prototype is to get efficient re-use of them among all instances of that object.
2. `onAccept()` will already receive a socket object as its only argument since it's a `'connection'` event handler, so just add that to `onAccept()`'s function signature and use it:

   ```
   Server.prototype.onAccept = function (socket) {
     // ...
   };
   ```